# Stacking of models giving black image with 0 as peak and minimum value

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, image-classification, ensemble-learning

When I was individually using models, results were pretty good. But while using the below code for stacking models, the result is a black file with 0 as peak value.

The file size of individual results is the same.

```py
estimator_list = [
    ('svm_l',SVC(kernel = 'linear', random_state = 0)),
    ('dt',DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion = 'entropy', random_state = 0)),
    ('rf',RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=80,n_jobs=-1))]

# Build stack model
stack_model = StackingClassifier(
    estimators=estimator_list, final_estimator=LogisticRegression())

# Train stacked model
stack_model.fit(data, label)
```

[result of stacking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyaNV.png)

Comment: Hi there  Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As written, it's unclear what the goal is, or what the expected output is.

Comment: I wanted to do image classification using a combination of models namely RandomForest and Logistic Regression by using the StackModel technique. The results of classification after using random forest and LogisticRegresion individually were accurate but when i am using combination of RF and LR results are full black images in results.